# Dynamically allocating space for a string from a string

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory-management, malloc

This is a very complex idea I am working with I suppose

```
int capacity = 100;
name = malloc(capacity * sizeof(char));
int len = 0;
char* i;
for (i = str; *i; i++) {
    if (len >= strlen(name)) {
        capacity *= 2;
        name = realloc(name, len * sizeof(char));
    }
    len++;
}
```

Assume `name` is declared already as a char pointer and `str` is passed in as a parameter. Why would this not work to double the size of an array?

Another approach I took was

```
int nameLength = 0;
int capacity = 100;
char* name = NULL;
double price = 0.0;
int position = 0;
if (sscanf(str, "add %s %lf %n", name, &price, &position)) {
    nameLength = capacity - position;
    capacity += nameLength;
    name = realloc(name, capacity * sizeof(char));
} else {
    name = malloc(REMAINING_MAX * sizeof(char));
}
```

Where I tried to take advantage of the `%n` format specifier.

Comment: `strlen` won't give you the capacity.

Comment: what will give me the capacity? Okay, sizeof, but that doesn't work for me

Comment: Your variable `capacity`. There is no way, in C, to get the capacity of a allocated chunk of memory. You have to remember it yourself somehow.

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: gfys usc fun kma jamf

Answer (score 1):

[`strlen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) is used to know how many useful character are stored inside a string. For that, it count how many char are set before viewing NULL char which terminate the string `\0` (the sentinel).

You are passing an uninitialized value to this function: this is a Undefined Behavior. Indeed, `name` is initialized with `malloc` but allocated memory (ie value pointed by name) still uninitialized! String pointed by name can store any kind of values. And it is impossible to know what will happen: it will fail, or if you are not lucky it will run correctly (until, a future crash). So *NEVER* use unitialized value.

So, to remember capacity, you have to store it. An good approach is to store both pointer and capacity to a structure to be sure that both are never separated:

```
struct ResizeableString {
    size_t capacity;
    char * str;
};
```